# BVP where $u$ is finite as $x\rightarrow 0^+$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, boundary-value-problem

> I am trying to solve the boundary value problem
>   $$x^2u''+2xu'-2u=18x^4 \ \ \ \ 0<x<2,$$
>   $$u \ \text{is finite, as }  x\rightarrow 0^+$$
>   $$u'-u=0 \ \ \ \ \text{at} \ x=2$$

My attempt:

I have shown that the general solution is $$u(x)=u_H(x)+u_P(x)=C_1x^{-2}+C_2x+x^4.$$
I have also shown that the second condition yields $$C_1+2C_2=32.$$
However, I am unsure how to utilise the first condition. How can $u$ be finite when $C_1x^{-2}\rightarrow\infty$ as $x\rightarrow 0^+$? A hint would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \lim_{x \to 0+} u(x)$ finite implies $C_1=0$ and this gives $C_2=16$.

Comment: Why does this imply $C_1=0$?

Comment: $\lim C_2x+x^{4}=0$. So if $\lim u(x)$ exists we can conclude that $\lim C_1x^{-2}$ must exist. Since $\lim_x\to 0 x^{-2}=\infty $ it follows that $\lim C_1x^{-2}$ can exist only when $C_1=0$. (Consider the cases $C_1>0$ and $C_1<0$ to see that the limit does not exist in these cases).

Comment: I think I understand. $C_1=0$ is necessary to insure $u$ is finite. If $C_1>0$ and $C_1<0$, does $C_1x^{-2}\rightarrow \infty$ and $-\infty$ respectively? Hence $u$ is not finite and thus $C_1$ must be $0$.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the argument.